# How to obtain a list of workspaces using Rally REST .NET

Tags: rally

I'm trying to obtain a list of available workspaces for a given Rally subscription, but it doesn't seem like the actual workspaces are being returned in the query.

Here's what I have so far:

```
        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi("username", "password");
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        Request request = new Request("Subscriptions");
        request.Fetch = new List<string>(){
            "Name",
            "SubscriptionID",
            "Workspaces"
        };

        QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request);

        foreach (var result in queryResult.Results)
        {
            var workspaces = result["Workspaces"];
        }
```

I can't seem to tease the workspace references or names out of that QueryResult. Am I missing an extra step/query?

Comment: This problem is specific to v2.0. It seems like this is fairly easy to do in earlier versions. I tried this in v1.40 and the workspaces were included in the subscription query result. I'm just not sure what I'm missing in v2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v2.0 removed the ability to return child collections in the same response for performance reasons.  Now fetching a collection will return an object with the count and the url from which to get the collection data.

Example: /subscription/12345/workspaces

The recently released [2.0 version of the .NET Rest Toolkit](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/releases/tag/v2.0) supports WSAPI v2.0 and collection querying.

```
RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi("username", "password");

//get the current subscription
DynamicJsonObject sub = restApi.getSubscription("Workspaces");

//query the Workspaces collection
QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(new Request(sub["Workspaces"])); 

foreach (var result in queryResult.Results)
{
    var workspaceRef = result["_ref"];
    var workspaceName = result["Name"];
}
```

Comment: I know it's been over 2 years, but this isn't working now. I'm getting: The best overloaded method match for 'Rally.RestApi.RallyRestApi.Query(Rally.RestApi.Request)' has some invalid arguments... maybe a minor tweak is necessary? If I find the answer I'll post it here.

Comment: Rally.RestApi.Request request = new Request("project");
            request.Workspace = "/workspace/12480728748";
            Rally.RestApi.Response.QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request);
this worked. got it from http://ask.programmershare.com/86_19729095/

Comment: Just submitted an edit, you need to construct a Request object as an intermediary between sub["Workspaces"] and the Query method. As Request takes a DynamicJsonObject but Query does not.