# RallyApi.Net Getting Workspaces from a Subscription Version 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, rally

Following this link [How to obtain a list of workspaces using Rally REST .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755778/how-to-obtain-a-list-of-workspaces-using-rally-rest-net)

I tried the example however when I try to query against sub["Workspaces"] I get the error

RuntimeBinderException was unhandled;

The best overloaded method match for 'Rally.RestApi.RallyRestApi.Query(Rally.RestApi.Request)' has some invalid arguments

I cannot find any other ways to gather a list of workspaces from the subscription using the RallyApi dll for .Net which I obtained from the link provided.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify that code as follows:

```
Request wRequest = new Request(sub["Workspaces"]);          
QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(wRequest);
```

Here is an entire app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Rally.RestApi;
using Rally.RestApi.Response;

namespace Rest_v2._0_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Initialize the REST API
            RallyRestApi restApi;
            restApi = new RallyRestApi("user@co.com", "secret", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "v2.0");

            //get the current subscription
            DynamicJsonObject sub = restApi.GetSubscription("Workspaces");

            Request wRequest = new Request(sub["Workspaces"]);

            //query the Workspaces collection
            QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(wRequest);

           foreach (var result in queryResult.Results)
            {
                var workspaceReference = result["_ref"];
                var workspaceName = result["Name"];
                Console.WriteLine( workspaceName + " " + workspaceReference);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution worked. I apologise if my question was simple, I am still learning this new code ;)